# Delete a particular element from an array using mongoose and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete a particular image from array after the user presses delete button 
Eg.

```
router.get("/delete_image/:id/:image", (req, res) => {
    const image = req.params.image;
        Image.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { $pullAll: { image: [image] } })
});
```

Suppose user wants to delete image.png, then I want to delete image.png from my database

```
[{
id:1,
image:images.png
},
{
id:2,
image:images2.png
}]
```

Comment: Can you add the `schema` for Image?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each document has an array of `images`, and you want to remove one specific elemtent from the array you can simly use [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) instead of `$pullAll`:

```
const imageName = req.params.image;
Image.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { $pull: { images: { image: imageName }} });
```